# Vertical data and counts

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a dataset that looks like this

tbMultipurposeVertical

```
id    parent   label     value
1       1      TopicID       1
2       1      Name       Chris
3       1      Selector    140
4       3      Selection   True
5       5      TopicID       1
6       5      Name         Matt
7       5      Selector      140
8       7      Selection    False
```

speaking_opportunities

TopicID      TopicName           duration     available
    1                 Networking          20 min                10
    2                Programming          20 min               10
    3                    Security               20 min               14
    4                Business                20 min                  10

I was creating a query that I am using to try to count the number of Selections that are true.  Here is my query.

```
SELECT     A.eventid, A.label, A.value, COUNT(*) AS Taken
FROM         tbMultipurposeVertical AS A INNER JOIN
                      Speaking_Opportunities AS B ON A.value = B.TopicID
WHERE     (A.eventid = 'Q6UJ9A010X2B') AND (A.label = 'Topic ID')
GROUP BY A.label, A.eventid, A.value, B.Available
```

I am looking for this

```
EventID          label   topicid   Selected
333333333333    Topic ID    1        2
333333333333    Topic ID    5        1
333333333333    Topic ID    6        1
```

Right now I am getting back the records that have a label = selection and value equaling true or false.  I only want to count the ones that have been selecte

Comment: what are you getting instead?

Comment: It is very helpful when posting question you show schema for both tables. I do not think your data matches your query at all. Columns are missing or miss names, and one of the tables is not show. This is a fairly easy query if both tables are shown

Comment: Im getting back the counts where label = 'selection' and value = true | false. I need the counts for where label = 'selection' but only want to count where value = true and they also need to be grouped by topic id